# Why git pull updates some files after git rebase?

Tags: git, github

I have seen a phenomena a lot, which really confuses me.  I am at my local master branch, I `git rebase origin/master` first and `git log` shows my head is at `origin/master`.  When I `git pull`, some new files are updated but I expect nothing should be updated.  Why this happened? Shouldn't `git rebase` & `git pull` both update my local file the same as the `origin/master`.

Comment: Git commits are snapshots. Not diffs. Keep that in mind and it may help explain what you’re seeing.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to fully understand what is the question so I'll do my best to answer and please LMK if I'm missing something:

The command `git rebase origin master` doesn't fetch remote branch, it will only rebase from the current status of your local "origin/master" branch (AKA the last time you fetched the remote master branch).

When running `git pull origin master` you're actually running `git fetch origin master & git rebase origin master` (or git merge, depends on your git settings).

Answer (score 0):

But if you start with a rebase *without fetching*, you are working on how **origin/master** *was* last time you fetched or pulled.... might have happened stuff since then... like what you see when you pull (because pull fetches). Try starting the flow with `git fetch` and it's highly unlikely it will happen (possible, but unlikely).